# parsing xml file and its elements in R

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to parse a XML file that has the following structure

```
 <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://12345hc.com/xsd">
            <xs:complexType name="Context">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="aNum" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="aId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="bURI" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="facility" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="fSessionId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ID" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="pwrd" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="profileID" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sToken" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="uNum" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="webURI" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="xZRT" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
```

I trying to select the node having `name="Context"` tag,

within this tag select the element labeled as ID,
`<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ID" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>`

and add value "111111" to this element `ID`.

Any pointers/answers on accomplishing this will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `xml2` package has all you need for parsing, but for writing you'll need to dive into the `XML` package, which is kind of huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
txt <- '<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://12345hc.com/xsd">
            <xs:complexType name="Context">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="aNum" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="aId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="bURI" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="facility" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="fSessionId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ID" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="pwrd" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="profileID" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sToken" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="uNum" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="webURI" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="xZRT" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>'
library(XML)
xml <- xmlParse(txt, asText=TRUE)
ns <- getNodeSet(xml, '//*[@name="Context"]/xs:sequence/xs:element')
id <- which(sapply(ns, xmlGetAttr, "name") == "ID")
xmlValue(ns[[id]]) <- "11111"
xml
# <?xml version="1.0"?>
# <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://12345hc.com/xsd">
#   <xs:complexType name="Context">
#     <xs:sequence>
#       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="aNum" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
#       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="aId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
#       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="bURI" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
#       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="facility" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
#       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="fSessionId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
#       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ID" nillable="true" type="xs:string">11111</xs:element>
#       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="pwrd" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
#       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="profileID" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
#       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sToken" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
#       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
#       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
#       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="uNum" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
#       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="webURI" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
#       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="xZRT" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
#     </xs:sequence>
#   </xs:complexType>
# </xs:schema>
```

Comment: Fantastic! I had a hard time passing the right parameters within the `getNodeSet` function. This is perfect. Thank you very much